# Illustrate NSLayoutConstraint to frame

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I want to get my layer layout information from server, by `JSON` string. and the layout information is same structure as `NSLayoutConstraint`.

```
[
    {
        "secondItem": "1", // id of second item, can be use to find the related layer, the first item is a existed layer
        "firstAttribute": "left", // same as NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute
        "secondAttribute": "left",
        "relation": "equal",    // same as NSLayoutRelation
        "multiplier": "1",
        "constant": "10"
    },

    {
        "secondItem": "1",
        "firstAttribute": "right",
        "secondAttribute": "right",
        "relation": "equal",
        "multiplier": "1",
        "constant": "10"
    },

    {
        "secondItem": "1", 
        "firstAttribute": "top",
        "secondAttribute": "top",
        "relation": "equal",
        "multiplier": "1",
        "constant": "10"
    },

    {
        "secondItem": "1",
        "firstAttribute": "bottom",
        "secondAttribute": "bottom",
        "relation": "equal",
        "multiplier": "1",
        "constant": "10"
    }
]
```

These `JSON` is just used to describe the `CALayer` layout information, not to apply to a `UIView` directly.

But how to illustrate `NSLayoutConstraint` to `CALayer` bounds and position property?

Thank you!

Comment: If you are applying NSLayoutConstraint, why do you bother about `frame` ?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining clearly. As I'm layout CALayer, I could not use NSLayoutConstraint directly. Using NSLayoutConstraint is because it's suitable for  init from JSON and enough to describe layout. Maybe using NSLayoutConstraint is a bad idea, but I have no other ideas.

Comment: could you put some example, like whats is your JSON input is, what is your expected output (Within UIView or Within CALayer).

Comment: I changed the decription, the json is input, the expect output is layout information of a CALayer. The json is a simple example, the acture situation may be the same with autolayout